# Placing logos and usernames in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm super new to all of this, I can only do some small edits but nothing more.
I need to put logos and usernames for Instagram, Facebook, Snapchat, Telegram like in the image but I really can't find anything. My english is not good enough to use the right search keywords for this neither. I need help. [How I want it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX9Ha.png)

Code: https://pastebin.com/dYHP8Rkb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Nax Corp.</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.timepicker.css">
 
   
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
 
    <div id="colorlib-page">
        <a href="#" class="js-colorlib-nav-toggle colorlib-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
        <aside id="colorlib-aside" role="complementary" class="js-fullheight text-center">
           
            <nav id="colorlib-main-menu" role="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                   
                    <li class="colorlib-active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
 
            <div class="colorlib-footer">
               
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </aside> <!-- END COLORLIB-ASIDE -->
       
           
             
 
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
        </div><!-- END COLORLIB-MAIN -->
    </div><!-- END COLORLIB-PAGE -->
 
  <!-- loader -->
  <div id="ftco-loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"><circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#F96D00"/></svg></div>
 
 
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scrollax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="js/google-map.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

I also need to change the pink color to Twitter logo blue one. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your HTML / CSS?

Comment: Hello, I added the source code in the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple HTML table:

```
<table style="height: 500px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>

<!-- LOGO 1 -->
<td style="width: 100%;">
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="/logo1.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Username1</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<!-- LOGO 2 -->
<td style="width: 100%;">&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="/logo2.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Username2</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<!-- LOGO 3 -->
<td style="width: 100%;">&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="/logo3.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Username3</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<!-- LOGO 4 -->
<td style="width: 100%;">&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="/logo4.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Username4</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There are other options you could use, which would be more ideal, such as CSS containers etc. But if you're looking for a quick fix, you can use the above.

(Please note, you need to change `/logo#.jpg` to your own images and `Username#` to your own text.)

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Any idea on how to add the logo on top of Home and Contact text on the left? Also, how do I change the pink color to blue? Thanks again. I appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, you would need to change the colour in your CSS. And regarding the logo, use the IMG tag, example `<img src="/logo.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="50" />` and you'd want to make this tag a child of your `<nav>` tag.